# ValueAnimators and programmatically added Views?

Tags: android, animation

When's the best time to start a ValueAnimator on a programmatically added View?

For example:

```
View v = new View; 
v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
viewGroup.addView(v); 
v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "translationY", v.getHeight() / 4, 0).start();
```

In this scenario, the `View` becomes immediately visible and drawn in the proper location. However, this animation does not do anything as `v.getHeight()` will initially return 0. The two workarounds for this are:

```
v.post(new Runnable() { 
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "translationY", v.getHeight() / 4, 0).start(); 
});
```

and

```
v.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) { 
            v.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
        } else { 
            v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this); 
        } 
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "translationY", v.getHeight() / 4, 0).start(); 
    } 
});
```

Both of these workarounds make sure that `v.getHeight()` returns the `View`'s actual height, instead of 0, by waiting for the system to calculate and measure the layout and `View`.

The issue is, when timing how long before `run()` or `onGlobalLayout()` is called, I'm getting numbers of up to 80ms, which means I'm waiting 5 frames before the `View` becomes visible! This is unacceptable from a user perspective, especially because if you don't attach a listener or post a Runnable, the view becomes visible immediately, albeit not animated.

Has anyone run into this issue before? Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you want it to have the initial height it has to be measured,  and it takes some time,  so patiently wait for it to happen

Comment: The thing is the initial height takes much less than 80ms to get measured. The fact that adding a `View` programmatically will result in  the view being drawn _at the proper location_ within one frame attests to that statement.

Comment: btw why are doing that by hand?  why not to use a TransitionManager?

Comment: @pskink, TransitionManager was added in KitKat, API level 19, so the vast majority of users wouldn't be able to see those animations. I know there are backports for that class but simply animating a programmatically added View shouldn't be this hard should it?

Comment: you're right,  it should not be that hard and it seems i don't really understand what your problem is :)